# Filtering data on basis of attribute values

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I am writing code to filter data on basis of attribute values. It is possible that the user can select multiple values.

How can this be better?

```
Models.Products filter(ViewModel.Filter search,IEnumerable<Models.Products> product)
{
    if (search.filter!= null && search.filter.Count>0)
        {
             var f = search.First();
             var tempProducts = products
                               .Where(c => c.productattributes
                                            .Where(a => a.AttributeId == f.Id && f.Value.Contains(a.Value))
                                            .Any());
             search.filter.Remove(f);
             foreach (var fs in search)
             {
                var p = products.Where(c => c.productattributes.Where(a => a.AttributeId == fs.Id && fs.Value.Contains(a.Value)).Any());
                tempProducts = tempProducts.Union(p);
             }
             products = tempProducts;
        }
}
```

Filter View Model:

```
public class Filters
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<string> Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Where's the `return`? I thought the _function_ in the method declaration was a _typo_ but there's more. Is this even working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code appears to be incomplete but I've provided some ideas below.

### Filters Class

I'm looking at your Filters class:

> ```
> public class Filters
> {
>     public long Id { get; set; }
>     public IEnumerable<string> Value { get; set; }
> }
> ```

From this, I am assuming that the purpose of this is to hold the Attribute Id (key) and Search Keywords (value). So, I would propose you just use a `Dictionary<long, List<string>>` -- note that I changed the type of your Search Keywords to a List as I am not seeing any reason within your code example as to why it should/would need to be an `IEnumberable` type.

That would then change the method:

- Method renamed
- Parameter updated to use `Dictionary` instead (per above)

Here is the updated method

```
public IEnumerable<Product> FilterProductsByAttributeId(
    Dictionary<long, List<string>> filters,
    IEnumerable<Product> products)
{
    // your method contents here
}
```

---

### Filter Method

I'm not sure why you have a complicated initializer for your `tempProducts`, but maybe it can be improved to something like this?

```
public IEnumerable<Product> FilterProductsByAttributeId(Dictionary<long, List<string>> filters, IEnumerable<Product> products)
{
    if (products == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(products));
    if (filters == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(filters));

    IEnumerable<Product> result = new List<Product>();
    foreach (var f in filters)
    {
        result = result.Union(products.Where(p => p.ProductAttributes
            .Where(a => a.AttributeId == f.Key && f.Value.Contains(a.Value)).Any()));
    }

    return result;    
}
```

Alternatively you can use the `Aggregate` extension:

```
return 
    filters
        .Aggregate(
            new List<Product>(), 
            (current, next) => current.Union(..)
        );
```

Comment: I hope you don't mind the edit ;-)

Comment: Not a problem. I appreciate the help! It seems you had a typo also! Haha